# Change div height with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm trying to change dynamically a div height, it depends on a table height.
Here is my code :

```
<div>
    <table class="responsive">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Ref</th>
                <th>Version</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="pinned">
    <table class="">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Ref</th>
                <th style="display: none;">Version</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td style="display: none;">2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to have the same size for **.pinned** and **.responsive**. Or the same size for **.pinned th** and **.responsive th** .

I tried that :

```
hauteur = jQuery('.responsive').height();
jQuery('.pinned').css('height', hauteur);
```

It works if I add IDs but tables are generated dynamically so... I would like to try without IDs.

What should I do?

Comment: Is `.responsive` class applied to single element?

Comment: Please share complete relevant code or create `jsfiddle`. The `javascript` code is not complete. When you're changing height?

Comment: But here you are using classes? So it should work? or try jQuery('.pinned').height(hauteur);

Comment: It works on jsfiddle but not in my code... I'll check it. Thanks for your help. http://jsfiddle.net/kh9yunbt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? You need to add "px" as $JqueryKing mentioned.

```
$('.pinned').each(function(){
    $(this).css('height', $('.responsive').height()+"px");
});
$('.pinned th').each(function(){
    $(this).css('height', $('.responsive th').height()+"px");
});
```

And if these are being added "on the go" you have to put this in a function and then run it every x ms.

Comment: What if there are multiple elements having `responsive` class?

Comment: @Tushar The way I saw it was that the `.responsive` was an element to follow. So that there will only be one. The `responsive` element should have the right dimensions which means that if there are multiple they should all be responsive. Otherwise there's no point naming it `responsive`.

Answer (score 1):

Following code should work:

```
jQuery('.pinned').height(jQuery('.responsive').height());
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the code in question?

Comment: Using the height jQuery function instead of css!

Comment: Nothing, but you need to add `+"px"`!